# C# - After executing the remove statement , list stays the same

Tags: c#, list, yield

Everyone , I tried to remove item based on condition but it seems that after executing the remove statement my list stays the same .

class `Menu`

```
  public class Menu : Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tạo mới guid khi gọi tới menu
    /// </summary>
    public Menu()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Id = rnd.Next(1,999999) * DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Danh sách Role
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM01))]
    public ICollection<string> Roles { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Danh sách Permisions
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM02))]
    public ICollection<string> Permisions { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Tên của từng menu
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM03))]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM07))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Đường dẫn
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM09))]
    [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM08))]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Mỗi menu sẽ chứa một loại menu
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<Menu> Items { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Mô tả thêm của từng menu
    /// </summary>
    [MaxLength(2000, ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM11))]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Loại menu
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM03))]
    [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM013))]
    public string EnumCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Icon của menu
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM016))]
    [MaxLength(1000, ErrorMessage = nameof(EnumManageMenu.ENM017))]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Trạng thái của menu
    /// </summary>       
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sắp xếp danh sách menu
    /// </summary>
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }


}
```

below is my code

```
 public async Task<MethodResult<List<MenuModel>>> GetAllMenuAsync()
    {
        MethodResult<List<MenuModel>> methodResult = new MethodResult<List<MenuModel>>();
        List<Menu> empty = new List<Menu>();
        List<Menu> menus = await _dbCollection.Find(FilterDefinition<Menu>.Empty).ToListAsync();
        empty = menus;
        int countList = menus.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < countList; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in GetListNoDel(menus[i]))
            {
                if (item.IsDeleted)
                {
                    empty.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
        List<MenuModel> menuModels = _mapper.Map<List<MenuModel>>(empty);
        methodResult.Result = menuModels;
        return methodResult;
    }
    private IEnumerable<Menu> GetListNoDel(Menu menus)
    {
        yield return menus;
        foreach (var item in menus.Items)
        {
            foreach (var items in GetListNoDel(item))
            {
                    yield return items;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that `empty = menus;` causes `empty` and `menus` to point to the same object in memory (i.e. you have one list that can be accessed through two variables).

Comment: Please show the definition of `Menu`. It doesn't seem like `List<Menu>` will include a menu's items, but maybe `Menu.Items` is a `List<Menu>` and those items are also in the list.

Comment: Check the return value from the `empty.Remove(item);` call. Something like `bool result = empty.Remove(item);` then check the result. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-6.0#returns

Comment: @GrantCarthew result is ``false`` what should i do to fix it?

Comment: So `menus` contains the menu items, and each menu item has an `Items` collection that contains some of the same menu items as `menus`, so you're trying to remove nested ones from the parent collection? I think you'll need to override `Equals` on `Menu` to do that, as although the nested items may contain the same data and have the same id, they aren't the same object in memory.

Comment: List.Remove(item) will remove "item" from the list, *if* it is found. But it will not search through child items - which your recursive GetListNoDel will also return. Your "menus" list (or "empty") will just contain the top-level items (as far as Remove knows), so only top-level items will be removed by this code

Comment: @HansKeﬆing how do I delete the child items in the parent list. Thanks

Comment: Child items are not in the parent list. You will have to search through your child lists (recursively) to find the correct item to delete. Maybe not just return the "item to delete", but also its parent (combine into a tuple, maybe) - then you have the correct parent to delete from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "foreach" over a list and immediately remove items (as you undoubtedly know). So you will have to first find the items to remove, and then remove them. A twist in your case is that those "items to remove" can be at any depth in a menu tree.

So when you find an item to remove, also remember which list it appears in. Then you can directly remove it from that list.

```
void MainMethod()
{
    var menulist = new List<Menu>(); // omitted: fill list
    
    // get the *full* list of items to remove, 
    // so you don't change a list that is still used in a foreach
    var todelete = ToDelete(menulist).ToList();

    // and remove them from their parent list
    foreach (var todo in todelete)
    {
        todo.list.Remove(todo.child);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<(List<Menu> list, Menu child)> ToDelete(List<Menu> menuitems)
{
    foreach (var item in menuitems)
    {
        if (item.IsDeleted)
        {
            // now we know that "item" must be removed from "menuitems"
            yield return (menuitems, item);
        }
        else
        {
            // if the parent is deleted, then all children will be gone as well
            //  - so only recursively check non-deleted items

            // pass the results of a recursive call up the call stack
            foreach (var pairs in ToDelete(item.Items))
            {
                yield return pairs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```